# Understanding Mac OS MPS Warning

Tags: macos, memory, graphics-card, cpu, gpu

**Context**

- Hardware: Mac M1 Mini
- Software

```
% sw_vers
ProductName:        macOS
ProductVersion:     13.5
BuildVersion:       22G74
```

Task at hand: Running a piece of Python Code (a Machine Learning Model).

I run it on CPU and does execute fine, so the code can not be the problem.

Running it in the GPU of my M1, the program crashes with the following error:

```
RuntimeError: MPS backend out of memory (MPS allocated: 5.34 GB, other allocations: 2.95 GB, max allowed: 9.07 GB). Tried to allocate 1.32 GB on private pool. Use PYTORCH_MPS_HIGH_WATERMARK_RATIO=0.0 to disable upper limit for memory allocations (may cause system failure).
```

I want help to understand a few things about the error, and maybe any suggestions for fixing it:

1. I inspected the GPU activity with powermetrics and it is not running currently as far as I understand:

```
**** GPU usage ****

GPU HW active frequency: 0 MHz
GPU HW active residency:   0.00% (396 MHz:   0% 528 MHz:   0% 720 MHz:   0% 924 MHz:   0% 1128 MHz:   0% 1278 MHz:   0%)
GPU SW requested state: (P1 :   0% P2 :   0% P3 :   0% P4 :   0% P5 :   0% P6 :   0%)
GPU SW state: (SW_P1 :   0% SW_P2 :   0% SW_P3 :   0% SW_P4 :   0% SW_P5 :   0% SW_P6 :   0%)
GPU idle residency: 100.00%
GPU Power: 0 mW
```

2. Any ideas on how to fix or inspect this ?